# Vertcally align text and text of float-right element

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a very simple table and I want to vertically align the text of two elements, one of which is plain text and the other is a button (I've put them in span tags, because I've been trying different things), so now the code snippet looks like that:

```
<tr>
   <td>element</td>
   <td>
      <span> test </span>
      <span>
           <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button>
      </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and

```
th, tr, td{
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Unfortunately no matter what I try, as long as I use the pull-right class it looks like this:

[image]

The "test" element just won't align in the middle or align with the "Delete" text of the button. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: If you were to take all the styles away the problem is no more, which means other css are affecting it, can you provide all the css related to the table and table elements ?

Comment: Set `display:inline-block` to test `span` and set its` line height`

Comment: What `float`...there's none in your code?

Comment: @ZohirSalak the css code I've provided for the tr and td elements is the only css for the table that I have added.

Comment: @Awais the inline-block somehow overwrites the pull-right and the button gets aligned on the left. If I give a line-height:50px it works, but I dont want to hardcode any values.

Comment: @Paulie_D the pull-right class contains float:right I think. It's the same wether I use .pull-right or style="float:right"

Comment: @coffee-and-code from the picture there's obviously more css and possibly a library, if you don't provide more context it'll be a guessing game

Comment: @ZohirSalak other than the bootstrap css the only table-related css I can find in the whole project is `table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
td,th{padding:0}` which has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Well right now with the coded provided, i can't reproduce the problem so the answers will only be guesses, So the class `pull-right` applies float to the element and floats takes the element out of the document flow so it won't be aligned, you should upgrade to bootstrap 4 and use `flex` for alignment

Comment: @coffee-and-code Then why not using `flex ` inside `td` which is best approach so far

Comment: @Awais if you using tables you must not touch the display property, because that's what makes table a table

Comment: @ZohirSalak i am not asking to change table style i just said that use the flex inside `td` like you do `display` properties on` div` isnide `td` like this `<td><div class="flex-container">  <div class="flex-item">1</div>  <div class="flex-item">2</div></div></td>` (You can write HTML inside table data)

Answer (score 0):

remove pull-right class and try this instead :

```html
<tr>
   <td>element</td>
   <td class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <span> test </span>
      <span>
           <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work as expected, the button just gets aligned on the left, next to the text element

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
span.test{
    line-height: 35px;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<tr>
   <td>element</td>
   <td>
      <span class="float-left test"> test </span>
      <span class="float-right">
           <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button>
      </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same without hardcoding the value of the line-height in pixels?